# alert message after delete not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have a code that calls my retrieve and delete php, both are working properly I can retrieve and delete data from db. I am getting the alert confirming if I want to delete the data which is good as well. But whenever I click YES or NO I am getting the message: **Record/s could not be deleted!**, instead of **Record/s has been deleted!** at all even if the record was indeed deleted from the database.

I am not posting my retrieve and delete php since they are both working. Just need to correct how the alert message would be displayed.

Here's my script that query and delete from db:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
            var xid = $('#XiD').val();
            var date = $('#Date').val();
            $.post('resultgenerator_test.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });

    $("#DeletefromDB").click(function() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record/s?"))
            var id = $('input[name=checkbox]:checked').map(function()
                {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
            $.post('deletedata_test.php',{id:id}, function(data)
            {
            $("#result").html(data);
            if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+id).remove();alert('Record/s has been deleted!');
            }

            else {
            alert('Record/s could not be deleted!');
            }
            document.messages.submit();
            return false;
        });                 
});
});
```

Comment: what are you returning in data from the server??

Answer (score 1):

Your `confirm` call is in an `if` statement that is not followed by a block of code within curly braces. As such only the next line (var id= etc.) depends on the `if`-statement. Change it to:

```
if(!confirm('Blaba'))
    return;
```

And your code should make a lot more sense. Also please ensure your indentation is correct when posting code, makes it easier for us *and you* to spot problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `if(data == 'true')` condition fails. Check what do get from your PHP when the delete is successful.

Also, if data is of type boolean, you should use `if(data)` instead of `if(data == 'true')`

And for solving record deletes even on NO, use the curly braces properly as suggested in @Niels answer